# Powershell compare issue

Tags: powershell, compare

I have 2 variables that I'm trying to compare. $Variable1 contains 3 columns of data, $Variable2 contains 1 column of data.

I need to compare column1 of $Variable1 to $Variable2. If there is a match, I want to return the value (all columns) of $Variable1.

Initially, I've tried:

$Variable1 -match $Variable2 and it works, but it returns too much data and I just want an exact match.

So then I tried $Variable1 -eq $Variable2 and it doesn't return anything. But if I use $Variable1.Column1 -eq $Variable2, then it returns the exact data that I want. But here, the problem is that it only returns Column1 of $Variable1 and I want all the columns of $Variable1 for that particular row of data. What should I do here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Where-Object` (alias `where`) in combination with an operator to achieve this result.

```
$variable1 | where column1 -in $variable2
```

You may also see the above written with the script block notation:

```
$variable1 | Where-Object { $_.column1 -in $variable2 }
```

This works when you want to filter a specific value against a list of values. If `$variable2` is always a single value, you can use `-eq` instead. You must send the object with all the possible properties you need into the pipeline and then filter the object values as needed. If you limit your object to one column/property before filtering, you will only output a filtered version of that one column.

---

The scenario above assumes a data set similar to below:

```
$var1 = [pscustomobject]@{c1=1;c2=2;c3=3},
        [pscustomobject]@{c1=2;c2=4;c3=6},
        [pscustomobject]@{c1=1;c2=6;c3=9},
        [pscustomobject]@{c1=6;c2=12;c3=13}
$var1 # array of objects with 3 properties

c1 c2 c3
-- -- --
 1  2  3
 2  4  6
 1  6  9
 6 12 13

$var2 # array of data

1
2
3

$var1 | where c1 -in $var2

c1 c2 c3
-- -- --
 1  2  3
 2  4  6
 1  6  9
```